# How to install flameshot version 9 or above on 20.04 LTS?

Tags: apt, 20.04, software-installation, screenshot

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.03 LTS *focal fossa*.

Recently, I heard of a screen capturing tool [known as Flameshot](https://flameshot.org/#:%7E:text=Flameshot%20allows%20users%20to%20simply,share%20the%20URL%20with%20others.). I installed it on my system using:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install flameshot
```

The installation went well and I was able to use flameshot. However, in the GIF on the [official GitHub page](https://github.com/flameshot-org/flameshot) they have shown many features, such as numbers, margins etc...

But I am unable to use the "numbering feature" and a few more features. It seems like the version available in the *focal* repositories is pretty old and does not seem to have these features.

Is there any way I can get these features in Ubuntu 20.04 *focal*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In 2022 we can avoid compilation by using Flatpak or Snap versions of Flameshot:

- [Flatpak](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.flameshot.Flameshot)

  ```
  sudo apt install flatpak
  flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
  flatpak install flathub org.flameshot.Flameshot
  ```
- [Snap](https://snapcraft.io/flameshot)

  ```
  sudo snap install flameshot
  ```

Appimage and .deb installers of the latest version are available at [GitHub releases](https://github.com/flameshot-org/flameshot/releases/).

Comment: Great answer N0rbert! The flatpak version is working great! However, the snap version isn't great at all... It's not even the official version! I would not like to use a development version.  But anyway, your answer is great! **+1**.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi I tried installing using the deb, it will fail because of dependency issues.

Comment: @Someone And the appimage? Also, several .deb packages are available. Do all of them have the dependency issue?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi I haven't tested the AppImage yet. But I just wanted to tell you that the deb file broke my docker completely! *All of them have issues?* Yes, they all depend on the latest version of libs.. Of course, I haven't tried all the deb packages but the ones I tried did have issues.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, you can [**compile the newer version**](https://github.com/flameshot-org/flameshot#compilation) of the package from source or install using Flatpak using [**the other answer**](https://askubuntu.com/a/1390544/1460940)

For compiling:

1. Satisfy Dependencies

   You need the following dependencies:

   ```
   Depends: libqt5svg5, libc6 (>= 2.14), libgcc-s1 (>= 3.0), libqt5core5a (>= 5.12.2), libqt5dbus5 (>= 5.0.2), libqt5gui5 (>= 5.10.0) | libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.10.0), libqt5network5 (>= 5.0.2), libqt5widgets5 (>= 5.11.0~rc1), libstdc++6 (>= 5.2)
   ```

   Also, install the suggested packages:

   ```
   Suggests: git, ca-certificates, openssl
   ```

   You also need the following packages to compile:

   ```
   g++ cmake build-essential qt5-default qttools5-dev-tools libqt5svg5-dev qttools5-dev
   ```

   So, simply run the following commands in a terminal:

   ```
   sudo apt update 
   sudo apt install g++ cmake build-essential qt5-default qttools5-dev-tools libqt5svg5-dev qttools5-dev
   sudo apt install libqt5dbus5 libqt5network5 libqt5core5a libqt5widgets5 libqt5gui5 libqt5svg5
   sudo apt install git openssl ca-certificates
   ```
2. Get Source Code

   Get the source code of the package by cloning the GitHub repository:

   ```
   cd ~/Downloads
   git clone https://github.com/flameshot-org/flameshot.git
   ```

   Change the working directory to `flameshot`:

   ```
   cd ~/Downloads/flameshot
   ```
3. Building

   Run the following commands to create a building environment:

   ```
   mkdir build
   cd build
   cmake ../
   ```

   Now run the `make` command with `sudo` privileges and get ready for the installation:

   ```
   sudo make
   ```
4. Install

   ***N.B**: It is really HARD to uninstall this installation. Only proceed if you want to install `flameshot` and are not planning to remove it in future*

   Finally, run:

   ```
   sudo make install
   ```

Now you can see that the latest version is installed!

<kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd>[image]</kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd>